# Json to Groovy list of objects

Tags: json, list, dictionary, object, groovy

I want to transform this json:

```
[
  {
    "askey": {
      "ad": "000001",
      "bt": 1
    },
    "Id": {
      "mc": 30,
      "zs": 476
    }
  }
]
```

into a list of objects in groovy.

I already tried with "map" but doing it wrong, for sure.

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText("""
[
  {
    "askey": {
      "ad": "000001",
      "bt": 1
    },
    "Id": {
      "mc": 30,
      "zs": 476
    }
  }
]
""")
json.each { println( it ) }
```

So that will be an array (ie java.util.List) because the root object is a json array, but I'm not sure what you want because the JSON only has 1 element in the root array.  So I'm unclear about how you want to transform it.

Comment: "So that will be an array because the root object is a json array" - i don't think that is true.  I expect the object returned from `parseText` to be an instance of `java.util.ArrayList`, not an array.

Comment: I think you are being too literal.  We're saying the same thing.  It'll be a JSON Array which in Java will be represented by some form of `java.util.List`.  When I said Array it's more of the conceptual idea (akin to JSON array) than a literal Java array.

Comment: "We're saying the same thing." - Excellent.  Thank you for your contribution.